# Storing data in classes or styling with data attributes. Which is better?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have some elements that should have both some data saved in them, and some styles applied.

Lets say i have a grid 4 x 4, like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/tM6ze/1/

I need to store the coordinates of each cell and use them via javascript, but also be able to style them individually.

I know i can save the data in the class itself like so:

```
<div class="cell row-3 col-3"></div>
```

and parse them in the js

I also know i can style cells in the css:

```
.grid .cell[data-row="3"][data-col="3"]{...some style...}
```

Both these approaches however are slower than the alternatives (get the data from data attributes and style with classes) i suppose.

So which one is more effective?
Or which one is best in what situations?

I guess i can include both classes and data in the elements (like in the fiddle), but is this the best approach?

Comment: If you know the dimensions of the grid, why not just `:nth-child`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would lean toward using data, simply because the `class` has multiple values and must either be parsed or matched.

Furthermore, your approach toward using classes amounts to a hack. You are storing data; why shouldn't you use data attributes?

As a plus, `data-` attributes are just a new kind of HTML attribute, and you should be able to manipulate them even if the browser doesn't support HTML5 (albeit with a bit more work).

Finally, libraries (frameworks, whatever) like jQuery have built-in methods for reading `data-` attributes, which (if you were to use them in the future) would simplify your code immensely.

There's nothing *wrong* with using classes the way you have done; it's just not necessary. Data tags are more appropriate, more clear, and easier to manipulate.